# How can I find out the number of the virtual desktop that displays a virtual terminal window running a shell?

Tags: linux, bash, linux-mint

Environment:

```
Linux Mint, Cinnamon desktop manager, with multiple workspaces=virtual desktops, e.g. 4.
Bash script
```

What is known:

```
How to determine the number of workspaces:

wmctrl -d | wc -l
```

What I need:

```
Get the number of virtual desktops the bash script is running on with a pure bash as var (like with grep, not awk or similar) and echo the var.
```

Comment: A bash script doesn't run on any kind of desktop. You can place a window of a virtual terminal that runs a shell that runs your script on a particular desktop, but there doesn't have to be a virtual terminal or a window. Some terminals *may* set an environment variable like `WINDOWID`, and a window *may* have a `_NET_WM_DESKTOP` property set on it, which, knowing its window id, you can query with `xprop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use POSIX shell features and the `xprop(1)` command to get both details with no other external utilities.

To get the ID number of the current/active desktop:

```
curdesk=$(xprop -root -notype _NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP)
curdesk="${curdesk##* }"
```

To get the count/quantity of desktops defined:

```
deskcnt=$(xprop -root -notype _NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS)
deskcnt="${deskcnt##* }"
```

Both depend on `xprop(1)` giving the answer in the form "`foo = 0`" (separated by spaces), and use shell pattern matching parameter expansion to match the longest substring ending in space, and remove it, leaving only the last token (the value after the equals sign).

Note that desktops are numbered from 0 (zero), so the count will be a number one higher than the ID number of the last desktop.

This should work with any window manager that adheres to the Extended Window Manager Hints (EWMH) specification (which is practically all of them, these days):

https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s03.html

Comment: The system refuses to send you a bonus of 50, so I'll put you on the status "Accepted solution" until it works. Please inform me if I forget.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` (imho still the most appropriate choice for the task at hand):

```
nr_of_active_workspace=$(wmctrl -d | awk '/\*/{print $NF}')
echo $nr_of_active_workspace
```

Or a `pure bash` solution:

```
nr_of_active_workspace=$(wmctrl -d | while read -r line; do [[ $line =~ '*' ]] && echo ${line: -1} ; done)
echo $nr_of_active_workspace
```